# Multiple Checkbox Filtering to Narrow Down a Search

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, search, filtering

Thank you to Khalid Ali for helping me so far up to this point.

So I have an array of songs that have descriptions, keywords etc. I have a number of checkboxes that I would like to use to refine a search. Basically, if someone selects the Pop checkbox it will show all songs with the genre "pop". However, if I also select Epic Trailers, it returns all songs with "pop" AND all songs with "epictrailers" in their genre. What I would like is for it to return songs with both genres only. For example - genre: "pop, epictrailers",

In the array below you'll see that song 2 and song 3 both have "dramatic" in moods. But song 2 also has "tense" and song 3 also has "soaring". So if I check the Dramatic and Soaring checkboxes I should only see song 3. At the moment both songs show because both songs have "dramatic".

So in short, I want it to return only songs that include ALL checked boxes.

I hope this makes sense...

**HTML SNIPPETS:**

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="search-music">
    <input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Enter a keyword to refine your search"/>
  </div>

  <div class='filterboxes'>
            <div class="genres"><h1>GENRES</h1><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="rock" key="genre" value="rock" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="rock">Rock</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Pop" key="genre" value="pop" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Pop">Pop</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="funk" key="genre" value="funk" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="funk">Funk</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Jazz" key="genre" value="jazz" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Jazz">Jazz</label><br>
          </div>
            <div class="genres"><P></P><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Dubstep" key="genre" value="dubstep" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Dubstep">Dubstep</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Classical" key="genre" value="classical" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Classical">Classical</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Country" key="genre" value="country" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Country">Country</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Blues" key="genre" value="blues" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Blues">Blues</label><br>
          </div>
          <div class="genres"><P></P><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Hip Hop" key="genre" value="hiphop" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Hip Hop">Hip Hop</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Orchestral" key="genre" value="orchestral" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Orchestral">Orchestral</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Epic Trailer" key="genre" value="epictrailer" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Epic Trailer">Epic Trailer</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="EDM" key="genre" value="edm" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="EDM">EDM</label><br>
            </div>
            <div class="genres"><h1>MOODS</h1><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Melancholy" key="moods" value="melancholy" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Melancholy">Melancholy</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Upbeat" key="moods" value="upbeat" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Upbeat">Upbeat</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Playful" key="moods" value="playful" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Playful">Playful</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Hopeful" key="moods" value="hopeful" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Hopeful">Hopeful</label><br>
          </div>
            <div class="genres"><P></P><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Dramatic" key="moods" value="dramatic" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Dramatic">Dramatic</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Disturbing" key="moods" value="disturbing" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Disturbing">Disturbing</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Uplifting" key="moods" value="uplifting" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Uplifting">Uplifting</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Tense" key="moods" value="tense" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Tense">Tense</label><br>
          </div>
          <div class="genres"><P></P><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Crazy" key="moods" value="crazy" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Crazy">Crazy</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Funny" key="moods" value="funny" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Funny">Funny</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Soaring" key="moods" value="soaring" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Soaring">Soaring</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Childish" key="moods" value="childish" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Childish">Childish</label><br>
            </div>
            <div class="genres"><h1>TEMPO</h1><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="vfast" key="tempo" value="vfast" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="vfast">Very Fast</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="fast" key="tempo" value="fast" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="fast">Fast</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="moderate" key="tempo" value="moderate" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="moderate">Moderate</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="slow" key="tempo" value="slow" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="slow">Slow</label><br>
          </div>
            <div class="genres"><h1>THEMES</h1><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Corporate" key="theme" value="corporate" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Corporate">Corporate</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Technology" key="theme" value="technology" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Technology">Technology</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Food" key="theme" value="food" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Food">Food</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Education" key="theme" value="education" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Education">Education</label><br>
          </div>
            <div class="genres"><P></P><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Travel" key="theme" value="travel" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Travel">Travel</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Sport" key="theme" value="sport" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Sport">Sport</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Fashion" key="theme" value="fashion" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Fashion">Fashion</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Landscape" key="theme" value="landscape" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Landscape">Landscape</label><br>
          </div>
          </div>


  <template v-for='song in filteredSongs'>
    <div class="songlayout" >
      <div class='wrapper'>
        <div>
          <img :src="song.cover_art_url" alt="" class='img-fluid rounded'>
        </div>
        <button class="button_7" @click='openLicense(song.license_url)'>License</button>
        <h1 class='song-title'>{{song.title}}</h1>
        <p class="song-description" >{{song.description}}</p>

        <div class="overlay-play text-center" v-if="isPlaying && (currentSong.id === song.id )" @click='pause'>
          <i class="icon ion-ios-pause"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="overlay-play text-center" @click='play(song)' v-else>
          <i class="icon ion-ios-play"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

**JS SNIPPET:**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    songs: [
            {
        id: 1,
        title: "Track 1",
        description: "Description 1",
        url:"./mp3/track1.mp3",
        keywords: "achievement, advertising, background, beautiful, beauty, business, business music, commercial, company, confident, corporate, corporate background, corporate presentation, corporate presentations music, corporate video, corporation, corporative, happy",
        genre:"pop, rock",
        moods:"uplifting, upbeat, playful",
        tempo:"moderate",
        theme:"corporate",
      },

      {
        id: 2,
        title: "Track 2",
        description: "Description 2",
        url:"./mp3/track2.mp3",
        keywords: "scary, horror, Armageddon, Big Ending, Dramatic, End Of The World, Escape, Fantasy, Film, Film Score, Foreboding, Haunted House, Haunting, Nervous, Nightmare, Pensive",
        genre:"epictrailer",
        moods:"tense, dramatic, disturbing",
        tempo:"moderate",
        theme:"landscape",
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: "Track 3",
        description: "Description 3",
        url: "./mp3/track3.mp3",
        keywords:"Armageddon, Battle, Big Ending, Bomb, Break Out, Busy, Chase, Chilled, Covert Ops, Detective,",
        genre:"epictrailer",
        moods:"dramatic, soaring, hopeful",
        tempo:"moderate",
        theme:"sport",
      },
          ],

    search: "",
    checkboxFilter: [],
  },
  computed: {
    filteredSongs: function(value, key){
    let fltrdSongs;
    if(this.checkboxFilter.length > 0) {
      fltrdSongs = this.songs.filter((song) => {
        let length = this.checkboxFilter.length;
        while(length--){
          if ((song.genre + song.moods + song.theme + song.tempo).indexOf(this.checkboxFilter[length])!=-1)
           {return true;}

        }
      });
    } else {
      fltrdSongs = this.songs;
    }

    return fltrdSongs.filter((song) => {
      return song.keywords.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
             song.title.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
             song.description.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase())
    });
},},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `filteredSongs` **computed property** never reaches the `this.checkboxFilter.length` if statement because of the `return` statement before it.

Replace your `filteredSongs` computed property with the following one:

```
filteredSongs: function(value, key){
    let fltrdSongs;
    if(this.checkboxFilter.length > 0)
      fltrdSongs = this.songs.filter((song) => (song.genre)
                                     .includes(this.checkboxFilter.toString()));
    else
      fltrdSongs = this.songs;

    return fltrdSongs.filter((song) => {
      return song.keywords.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
             song.title.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
             song.description.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase())
    });
}
```

---

In response to [jeanpegg's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55733196/how-to-use-search-and-checkbox-filters-in-vue-js/55734322?noredirect=1#comment98148339_55734322)

Use the following **computed property** to filter the *songs* by multiple checkboxes:

```
filteredSongs: function(value, key){
    let fltrdSongs;
    if(this.checkboxFilter.length > 0) {
      fltrdSongs = this.songs.filter((song) => {
        let length = this.checkboxFilter.length;
        while(length--){
          if ((song.genre).indexOf(this.checkboxFilter[length])!=-1) {
            return true;
          }
        }
      });
    } else {
      fltrdSongs = this.songs;
    }

    return fltrdSongs.filter((song) => {
      return song.keywords.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
             song.title.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
             song.description.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase())
    });
}
```

---

In response to [jeanpegg's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55733196/multiple-checkbox-filtering-to-narrow-down-a-search#comment98151193_55734322)

I've edit the code to work with the *genre* and *moods*.

HTML: changing `v-model="checkboxFilter"` to `v-model="checkboxFilter.genre"` and `v-model="checkboxFilter.moods"`

JS: changing the `checkboxFilter` **data property** to `checkboxFilter: {genre: [], moods: []}`. Also changed the `filteredSongs` **computed property**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script><div id="app">
  <div class="search-music">
    <input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Enter a keyword to refine your search"/>
  </div>

  <div class='filterboxes'>
            <div class="genres"><h1>GENRES</h1><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="rock" key="genre" value="rock" v-model="checkboxFilter.genre">
            <label for="rock">Rock</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Pop" key="genre" value="pop" v-model="checkboxFilter.genre">
            <label for="Pop">Pop</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="funk" key="genre" value="funk" v-model="checkboxFilter.genre">
            <label for="funk">Funk</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Jazz" key="genre" value="jazz" v-model="checkboxFilter.genre">
            <label for="Jazz">Jazz</label><br>
          </div>
            <div class="genres"><P></P><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Dubstep" key="genre" value="dubstep" v-model="checkboxFilter.genre">
            <label for="Dubstep">Dubstep</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Classical" key="genre" value="classical" v-model="checkboxFilter.genre">
            <label for="Classical">Classical</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Country" key="genre" value="country" v-model="checkboxFilter.genre">
            <label for="Country">Country</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Blues" key="genre" value="blues" v-model="checkboxFilter.genre">
            <label for="Blues">Blues</label><br>
          </div>
          <div class="genres"><P></P><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Hip Hop" key="genre" value="hiphop" v-model="checkboxFilter.genre">
            <label for="Hip Hop">Hip Hop</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Orchestral" key="genre" value="orchestral" v-model="checkboxFilter.genre">
            <label for="Orchestral">Orchestral</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Epic Trailer" key="genre" value="epictrailer" v-model="checkboxFilter.genre">
            <label for="Epic Trailer">Epic Trailer</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="EDM" key="genre" value="edm" v-model="checkboxFilter.genre">
            <label for="EDM">EDM</label><br>
            </div>
            <div class="genres"><h1>MOODS</h1><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Melancholy" key="moods" value="melancholy" v-model="checkboxFilter.moods">
            <label for="Melancholy">Melancholy</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Upbeat" key="moods" value="upbeat" v-model="checkboxFilter.moods">
            <label for="Upbeat">Upbeat</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Playful" key="moods" value="playful" v-model="checkboxFilter.moods">
            <label for="Playful">Playful</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Hopeful" key="moods" value="hopeful" v-model="checkboxFilter.moods">
            <label for="Hopeful">Hopeful</label><br>
          </div>
            <div class="genres"><P></P><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Dramatic" key="moods" value="dramatic" v-model="checkboxFilter.moods">
            <label for="Dramatic">Dramatic</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Disturbing" key="moods" value="disturbing" v-model="checkboxFilter.moods">
            <label for="Disturbing">Disturbing</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Uplifting" key="moods" value="uplifting" v-model="checkboxFilter.moods">
            <label for="Uplifting">Uplifting</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Tense" key="moods" value="tense" v-model="checkboxFilter.moods">
            <label for="Tense">Tense</label><br>
          </div>
          <div class="genres"><P></P><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Crazy" key="moods" value="crazy" v-model="checkboxFilter.moods">
            <label for="Crazy">Crazy</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Funny" key="moods" value="funny" v-model="checkboxFilter.moods">
            <label for="Funny">Funny</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Soaring" key="moods" value="soaring" v-model="checkboxFilter.moods">
            <label for="Soaring">Soaring</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Childish" key="moods" value="childish" v-model="checkboxFilter.moods">
            <label for="Childish">Childish</label><br>
            </div>
            <div class="genres"><h1>TEMPO</h1><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="vfast" key="tempo" value="vfast" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="vfast">Very Fast</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="fast" key="tempo" value="fast" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="fast">Fast</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="moderate" key="tempo" value="moderate" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="moderate">Moderate</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="slow" key="tempo" value="slow" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="slow">Slow</label><br>
          </div>
            <div class="genres"><h1>THEMES</h1><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Corporate" key="theme" value="corporate" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Corporate">Corporate</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Technology" key="theme" value="technology" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Technology">Technology</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Food" key="theme" value="food" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Food">Food</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Education" key="theme" value="education" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Education">Education</label><br>
          </div>
            <div class="genres"><P></P><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Travel" key="theme" value="travel" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Travel">Travel</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Sport" key="theme" value="sport" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Sport">Sport</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Fashion" key="theme" value="fashion" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Fashion">Fashion</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Landscape" key="theme" value="landscape" v-model="checkboxFilter">
            <label for="Landscape">Landscape</label><br>
          </div>
          </div>


  <template v-for='song in filteredSongs'>
    <div class="songlayout" >
      <div class='wrapper'>
        <div>
          <img :src="song.cover_art_url" alt="" class='img-fluid rounded'>
        </div>
        <button class="button_7" @click='openLicense(song.license_url)'>License</button>
        <h1 class='song-title'>{{song.title}}</h1>
        <p class="song-description" >{{song.description}}</p>

        <div class="overlay-play text-center" v-if="isPlaying && (currentSong.id === song.id )" @click='pause'>
          <i class="icon ion-ios-pause"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="overlay-play text-center" @click='play(song)' v-else>
          <i class="icon ion-ios-play"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    isPlaying: '',
    songs: [
            {
        id: 1,
        title: "Track 1",
        description: "Description 1",
        url:"./mp3/track1.mp3",
        keywords: "achievement, advertising, background, beautiful, beauty, business, business music, commercial, company, confident, corporate, corporate background, corporate presentation, corporate presentations music, corporate video, corporation, corporative, happy",
        genre:"pop, rock",
        moods:"uplifting, upbeat, playful",
        tempo:"moderate",
        theme:"corporate",
      },

      {
        id: 2,
        title: "Track 2",
        description: "Description 2",
        url:"./mp3/track2.mp3",
        keywords: "scary, horror, Armageddon, Big Ending, Dramatic, End Of The World, Escape, Fantasy, Film, Film Score, Foreboding, Haunted House, Haunting, Nervous, Nightmare, Pensive",
        genre:"epictrailer",
        moods:"tense, dramatic, disturbing",
        tempo:"moderate",
        theme:"landscape",
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: "Track 3",
        description: "Description 3",
        url: "./mp3/track3.mp3",
        keywords:"Armageddon, Battle, Big Ending, Bomb, Break Out, Busy, Chase, Chilled, Covert Ops, Detective,",
        genre:"epictrailer",
        moods:"dramatic, soaring, hopeful",
        tempo:"moderate",
        theme:"sport",
      },
          ],

    search: "",
    checkboxFilter: {genre: [], moods: []},
  },
computed: {
  filteredSongs: function(value, key){
    let fltrdSongs = this.songs;
    // checking if "genre" and "moods" arrays have elements in any of them
    if(this.checkboxFilter.genre.length + this.checkboxFilter.moods.length > 0) {
      // checking if "genre" array has elements
      if (this.checkboxFilter.genre.length > 0) {
        fltrdSongs = this.songs.filter((song) => {
          let length = this.checkboxFilter.genre.length;
          while(length--){
            if ((song.genre).indexOf(this.checkboxFilter.genre[length])!=-1) {
              return true;
            }
          }
        });
      }
      // checking if "moods" array has elements
      if(this.checkboxFilter.moods.length > 0) {
        fltrdSongs = fltrdSongs.filter((song) => {
          let length = this.checkboxFilter.moods.length;
          while(length--){
            if ((song.moods).indexOf(this.checkboxFilter.moods[length])!=-1) {
              return true;
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }

    return fltrdSongs.filter((song) => {
      return song.keywords.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
             song.title.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
             song.description.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase())
      });
   }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Got it working now. If I could bother you one last time and ask how I could combine multiple checkboxes? For example, return a song with both genre (Pop) and tempo (Fast) checked? They work independently but it returns nothing when checking both boxes. Once again, thank you for helping me with the original question!

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help! I've edited my answer to add the code for filtering by multiple checkboxes. Let me know if you got it working properly. Thanks

Comment: Hi Khalid, thank you for helping me so far. I almost have it working exactly how I want it to. I have edited the question to try and explain how I want the songs to be filtered. You have been awesome in helping me and I really appreciate it!!!

Comment: Hi Jean, please check my newly edited answer and follow the same logic to add other filters. Let me know if there's anything else I can help you with.

Comment: Hi Khalid! This is perfect! Thank you so much for helping me to get this sorted. I really appreciate it! You are a star.